# How to restart a local hardhat node to initial state?

Tags: typescript, ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

I am not really sure how to restart the state of the node to the initial state. Each time I try to redeploy a contract - I'm getting the same contract, the constructor params don't change.

How to clean my local hardhat node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a lot longer than I'm proud to admit to figure it out, but here's the answer:

The node doesn't store the state. Every time you stop and start the node again - it is in the initial state. That's why it's important to have some scripts to set your initial node state, that is, get it in the wanted state before you do any further testing.

My previous experiences with Ganache confused me here. They are very different.

Comment: but why I get the same NFT when I restart the node

Comment: How are you running the node? @MURHAFAL-MSRI

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful for anybody coming upon this page, if you are attempting to programatically reset an independent running hardhat node that is running inside terminal (i.e. a node started in a terminal with `npx hardhat node`, and perhaps used in a testing environment with `hh test --network localhost`, you can do that programatically in your test suite as follows:as follows:

```
describe("suite", function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    await hre.network.provider.send("hardhat_reset")
  })
}}
```

This would clear out all deployed contracts and reset account balances to initial state (normally 20 accounts, each with balance of 10,000 Eth)

Comment: That is actually nice. One more thing to keep in mind is that all of the contracts would have to be redeployed.